# Como filtrar columnas de una tabla con checkbox en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-blade

Tengo una tabla que muestra unos datos desde la base de datos en MYSQL la cual tengo un checkbox que actúa como filtro el cual, debería validar que la ciudad del usuario conectado en la sesión sea igual a la ciudad de algún registro de mi tabla *complejos*, **y ocultar las demás columnas de la tabla** (en mi vista) **en donde los registros no pertenezcan a esa ciudad.**

De momento he probado esto, lo cual me oculta las columnas.

```
window.onload = function(){

    $('#empty').hide();
}

$("#filtro_check").on("change", function(){

    var ciudad = document.getElementById('input_comuna').value;

    if ($(this).prop('checked')){
        if ($('#input_complejo_id_user').val() == $('#input_id_complejo').val()){


            $('td:nth-child(1)').toggle();
            $('td:nth-child(2)').toggle();
            $('td:nth-child(3)').toggle();
            $('td:nth-child(4)').toggle();
            $('td:nth-child(5)').toggle();
            $('td:nth-child(6)').toggle();
            $('td:nth-child(7)').toggle();
            $('#empty').show();


        }
    }else if ($(this).prop('checked') == false) {

        $('td:nth-child(1)').toggle();
        $('td:nth-child(2)').toggle();
        $('td:nth-child(3)').toggle();
        $('td:nth-child(4)').toggle();
        $('td:nth-child(5)').toggle();
        $('td:nth-child(6)').toggle();
        $('td:nth-child(7)').toggle();
        $('#empty').hide();

    }
});
```

---

Y esta es la tabla.

```
@foreach($complejos as $comp)
    @if(Auth::user()->complejo_id == $comp->id)

        #ESTE ES EL CHECKBOX
        <input type="checkbox" id="filtro_check" name="filtro_check">
        <label for="filtro_check">Filtrar por ciudad</label>


        <input type="hidden" value="{{Auth::user()->complejo_id}}" id="input_complejo_id_user">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{$comp->comuna}}" id="input_comuna">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{$comp->id}}" id="input_id_complejo">
    @endif
@endforeach


<table width="100%" border="0" id="tabla_principal">
    <thead >
        <tr>
            <th class="th">Complejo</th>
            <th class="th">Dirección</th>
            <th class="th">Teléfono</th>
            <th class="th">Detalle</th>
            <th class="th">Fecha</th>
            <th class="th">Seleccionar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach($complejos as $complejo)
            <form method="POST" action="{{route('reservar-cancha-horarios',['id'=>$complejo->id])}}" name="form" id="form">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$complejo->nombre}}</td>
                    <td>{{$complejo->direccion}}</td>
                    <td>{{$complejo->telefono}}</td>

                    <td>
                      <input type="button" id="openModal">
                    </td>

                    <td style="padding-top: 5mm;">
                      <input type="date" name="fecha" required="required" id="fecha">
                    </td>

                    <td style="padding-top: 5mm;">
                      <input type="submit" name="guardar" id="btn_seleccionar" value="SELECCIONAR">

                    </td>
                    {!! Form::token() !!}
                </tr>
            </form>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>

<center>
    <label id="empty">Su busqueda no coincide con nuestros registros.</label>
</center>
```

---

También he probado con esto:

```
public function filtroCiudad($id){

  $user_id = User::find($id);
  $user_logged_id = Auth::user()->id;
  $complejo = Complejo::find($id);

  try {

      /*Además de la condición actual, cómo en el IF puedo preguntar 
      si el valor del campo $complejo->comuna es igual en todos los registros de mi tabla?? 

      Si se cumple debería mostrar todos los campos donde coincida la comuna o ciudad*/

      if ($user_logged_id == $user_id->id) {

        return view('reservas-cancha')->with('user', $user_id)->with('complejo', $complejo);
      }
  } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {

      Session::flash('error', 'Su búsqueda no coincide con nuestros registros');
      return view('reservas-cancha')->with('user', $user_id)->with('complejo', $complejo);  
  }
}
```

---

Y en mi vista tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
@if(Session::has('error'))
    <span class="error">{{Session::pull('error') }}</span>
@endif

<table width="100%" border="0" id="tabla_principal">
    <thead >
        <tr>
            <th class="th">Complejo</th>
            <th class="th">Dirección</th>
            <th class="th">Ciudad/Comuna</th>
            <th class="th">Detalle</th>
            <th class="th">Fecha</th>
            <th class="th">Seleccionar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    #O POSIBLEMENTE COLOCAR TAMBIÉN AQUÍ UN @FOREACH
        <tr>
            <td>{{$complejo->nombre}}</td>
            <td>{{$complejo->direccion}}</td>
            <td>{{$complejo->comuna}}</td>

            <td>                             
                <input type="button" class="detalle" id="btn_select" data-target="#myModal" value="DETALLE" data-toggle="myModal">
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type="date" name="fecha" class="date_control" required="required" id="fecha">
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="guardar" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn_seleccionar" value="SELECCIONAR">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Aunque no se muy bien de qué manera le puedo poner un foreach() para que me muestre todos los resultados que coincida la ciudad del usuario logueado, con la de la base de datos, de mi tabla de los complejos. Ya que tengo muchos registros con la misma ciudad y de ID diferentes cada uno.

Un ejemplo en como intento validar aquello es de una manera similar a la siguiente consulta realizada en MySQL.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También como información adicional agrego las relaciones entre las tablas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿cómo estás intentando hacer la consulta?

Comment: Ahora he estado probando en llamar a una ruta, en un `<form action="{{route('miruta/',['id'=>Auth::user()->id])}} method="POST"">`, cree la ruta y le establecí la función a ocupar, pero no me la toma.

Comment: ¿qué es lo que no toma? ¿qué datos se envían?

Comment: @Shaz. Ya solucione ese detalle. Ahora no logro mostrar los registros en donde la comuna o ciudad se repite.

Comment: Realmente no se entiende esta pregunta, tal vez sea mejor hacer una nueva para el problema que hay ahora.

Comment: Ese es el problema inicial, con el filtro mostrar las comunas o ciudades que coincidan con el usuario conectado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondo a mi pregunta, de momento logré filtrar los campos de la tabla según la ciudad del usuario logueado redireccionando a una vista diferente ***(Cuando mi idea era en la misma vista; pero tuve que hacerlo así ya que fue la manera que encontré y me funcionó)***

Para lograr aquello tuve que añadir un campo nuevo a mi tabla usuarios, la ciudad.

- Lo primero que se hizo fue cambiar el checkbox por un botón.

---

```
<div class="div_filtro">
    @foreach($complejos as $comp)
        @if(Auth::user()->complejo_id == $comp->id)

            <a href="{{route('filtro.ciudad', Auth::user()->id)}}">
                <input class="btn_ciudad" value="Filtrar por ciudad" type="button">
            </a>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
```

- Luego se creó la ruta a ocupar.

---

```
Route::get('reservar', ['uses' => 'Reservas@filtroCiudad', 'as'=>'filtro.ciudad']);
```

- Después en el controlador se creó la función que la ruta ocupa.

---

```
public function filtroCiudad(){


  $user_id = User::all();
  $user_logged_id = Auth::user()->id;
  $complejo = Complejo::all();

  try {
    foreach ($user_id as $user_id ) {

      if ($user_logged_id == $user_id->id) {

        return view('reservas-cancha')->with('user', $user_id)->with('complejo', $complejo);
      }
    }
  } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {

    Session::flash('error', 'Su búsqueda no coincide con nuestros registros');
    return view('reservas-cancha')->with('user', $user_id)->with('complejo', $complejo);  
  }
}
```

- Y por último en la vista nueva se muestran los campos que corresponden.

---

```
/*TODO ESTO ESTÁ DENTRO DE UNA TABLA (<table>) ya que al 
ser muy extenso el código solo copié la parte importante*/

@foreach($complejo as $complejo)
    @if($user->city == $complejo->comuna)
        <form method="POST" action="{{route('reservar-cancha-horarios',['id'=>$complejo->id])}}" name="form" id="form">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td id="td_1">{{$complejo->nombre}}</td>
                    <td id="td_2">{{$complejo->direccion}}</td>
                    <td id="td_3">{{$complejo->telefono}}</td>                                 
                    <td>                                             
                        <input type="button" class="detalle" id="btn_select" data-target="#myModal" value="DETALLE" data-toggle="myModal" data-id="{{$complejo->id}}" data-nombre="{{$complejo->nombre}}" data-direccion="{{$complejo->direccion}}" data-telefono="{{$complejo->telefono}}" data-comuna="{{$complejo->comuna}}" data-descripcion="{{$complejo->descripcion}}">
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="date" name="fecha" class="date_control" required="required" id="fecha">
                    </td>

                    <td>

                        <input type="submit" name="guardar" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn_seleccionar" value="SELECCIONAR">
                    </td>
                {!! Form::token() !!}
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </form>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

no comprendo totalmente lo que quieres hacer, pero si alcanzo a enteder el filtro de las ciudades, lo que deberias hacer es relacionar la tabla de usuarios con la de las ciudades de esta forma, tendras el idciudad en usuarios y cuando llamas la informacion en el for each compararas que los demas usuarios tengan el mismo idciudad del usuario logueado, en este caso compararas que complejo tenga el mismo idciudad de tu usuario entonces tambien tendras que relacionar complejo con ciudad:

```
 @foreach($complejos as $complejo)
        <tr>
            @if(Auth::user()->idciudad == $complejo->idciudad)
            <td>{{$complejo->nombre}}</td>
            <td>{{$complejo->direccion}}</td>
            <td>{{$complejo->comuna}}</td>              
          @endif
        </tr>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: Entiendo la idea pero en la base de datos, no tengo un id para la ciudad en ninguna de mis tablas, la validacion la hago a través del id del propio complejo, con el del usuario y el usuario conectado. (Tampoco hay una tabla ciudad) Pero ya probé de una manera similar a eso, y me muestra 1 registro solamente. Cuando lo que intento es preguntar si el nombre de la ciudad coincide en los registros, y si se cumple que muestre todo en donde coincida. Actualice la pregunta añadiendo esto último.

Comment: bien, deberias tambien añadir el mapa relacional de la BD para poder saber las relaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Viendo la BD, podrias traer todos los usuarios que tambien comparta la ciudad del logeado de esta manera:

```
/* importaciones laravel en controlador  */

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use DB;

/* Y esto deberia ir dentro del metodo del controlador    */

$user = Auth::user();

$complejoId = $user->complejo_id;

/* Se realiza consulta   */

$data = DB::select('SELECT u.name, u.lastname FROM users as u INNER JOIN complejo AS c ON u.complejo_id=c.id WHERE c.id = ?', array($complejoId));
```

al final con return llevas el dato donde quieras.

Comment: No dejes por favor múltiples respuestas a la misma pregunta, solo se responde una vez; si te hace falta información entonces dale editar a la primera respuesta y agrega eso ahí